# c++: why does this code make error? multiple linear regression

Tags: c++, linear-regression

I'm beginner of c++ and I'm making code about linear regression. 
First i made a code about single variable linear regression which has one x and one y variable,
and now i'm changing that code to multiple linear regression which has more than 2 x and one y.
and it's making error but i couldn't find why.

I won't write header file here. please think header has no error.
And original code hadn't any error.

original code :

```
double LinearRegression::predict(double x)
{
    return this->h(x);
}


double LinearRegression::h(double x)
{
    return this->w * x + this->b;
}
```

code about multiple variable :

```
double LinearRegression::predict(double x, int index)
{
    return this->h(x, index);
}


double LinearRegression::h(double x, int index)
{
    double sum = 0;

    // return this->w * x + this->b;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->multi_num; i++) {
        sum += this->w[i] * x[i][index];    // here x is making error
    }
    sum += this->b;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?  Also, what is the type of `x`?  Is it a 2d array?  It doesn't look like it is.

Comment: yes it's 2d array. for example 
x[] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}; 
y[] = {1,2,3};
2d array's contents are double.

Comment: `double LinearRegression::h(double x, int index)` says it is a double, not an array.

Comment: ah i should say that we know x and y, so when we enter x and y value we will calculate w and b using them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass `double** x` as the parameter to `predict` and `h` methods in the case of multiple linear regression. Currently, you are trying to manipulate a single double as a 2D array, which won't even compile.